# Hilbert envelope in scipy matches original signal

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I need to get Hilbert envelope plot over original sound but I can't understand why it doesn't work with my audio file.

[Envelope with my audio file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY33u.png)

[Envelope with different audio file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7cEV.png)

[Еxample of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64wpY.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import hilbert
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('signal.wav')
t = 100
data1 = data[:t]
plt.plot(data1)
plt.plot(np.abs(hilbert(data1)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding `data = ((data)) / ((max(data)/2)) - 1` before plotting

Comment: For future readers, consider embedding the images rather than adding links. Also, be sure to submit the answer for your own question, if you've solved it. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Type%20in%20your%20answer%2C%20then,better%20solution%20to%20your%20problem!)